# Using lambda for dynamic conditions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, conditional-statements

I define a has_many association with a dynamic condition like that:

```
class Checkin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :evaluations, :conditions => proc {"evaluations.placement_id = #{self.placement_id}"}
end
```

Assuming that checkin with id=1 has placement_id=2:

```
> Checkin.find(1).evaluations.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"evaluations\".* FROM \"evaluations\"  WHERE \"evaluations\".\"checkin_id\" = 1 AND (evaluations.placement_id = 2)"
```

As I prefer lambdas over procs, I'm trying to replace association conditions with lambda, but this attempt results in an error:

```
:conditions => lambda {"evaluations.placement_id = #{self.placement_id}"}

> Checkin.find(1).evaluations.to_sql
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

The error is easily fixed by providing an argument to lambda block:

```
:conditions => lambda {|a| "evaluations.placement_id = #{self.placement_id}"}

> Checkin.find(1).evaluations.to_sql # a is nil inside of this lambda call!
=> "SELECT \"evaluations\".* FROM \"evaluations\"  WHERE \"evaluations\".\"checkin_id\" = 1 AND (evaluations.placement_id = 2)"
```

Passing an argument makes no difference and lambda's parameter is always nil:

```
:conditions => lambda {|a| puts "a: #{a || 'undefined'}"; "evaluations.placement_id = #{self.placement_id}"}

Checkin.find(1).evaluations(5) # => has no effect on produced sql
a: undefined
# and here are returned evaluations
```

1. What is that required parameter of lambda block?
2. Why should it be there?
3. Why does that parameter always stay nil?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is due to `ActiveRecord::Associations::Association#interpolate`, which is called when Rails is determining association scope with conditions. The call looks like:

```
scope = scope.where(interpolate(condition))
```

Here is the full text of the `interpolate` method (from the 3.2 source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb):

```
def interpolate(sql, record = nil)
  if sql.respond_to?(:to_proc)
    owner.send(:instance_exec, record, &sql)
  else
    sql
  end
end
```

In this method, `sql` is your lambda condition and `owner` evaluates to the `Checkin` instance.

Lambdas respond to `to_proc` so the `if` condition is satisfied. So what's really going on is something like:

```
Checkin.find(1).instance_exec(nil) {"evaluations.placement_id ... "}
```

This doesn't work because `nil` is an argument, so the block should have one argument (you already know that lambdas check arity). When you do `lambda {|a| ... }`, `a` is `nil` because `record` is `nil` (because a value for it wasn't passed to the `interpolate` method and `nil` is the default value).